# How to mount docker socket as volume in docker container with correct group

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-docker

I want to run a Jenkins instance in a docker container.

I want Jenkins itself to be able to spin up docker containers as slaves to run tests in.

It seems the best way to do this is to use

```
docker run -v /var/run.docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 8080:8080 -ti my-jenkins-image
```

[source](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)

The `Dockerfile` I'm using is

```
FROM jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker.io
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
USER jenkins
```

If I start a bash session in my running container and run `docker info` on my image I get

```
$ docker info
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

And if I run the bash session as root

```
docker exec -u 0 -ti cocky_mccarthy bash
root@5dbd0efad2b0:/# docker info
Containers: 42
Images: 50
...
```

So I guess the `docker` group I'm adding the Jenkins user to is the group for the internal docker hence the socket is not readable without `sudo`. That's kind of a problem as the Jenkins docker plugin etc are not set up to use `sudo`.

**How can I mount the socket so it can be used from the image without `sudo`?**

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same issue right now

Comment: My solution is to change ownership on docker.sock after container is started. `docker exec -it -u root jenkins-docker chown jenkins /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: I mounted a socket, but I get `bash: docker: command not found`. Does anyone have a working example with Docker Compose?

Comment: I found that `/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` is mandatory to access host's `docker`  from inside a container.

Comment: There is wrong path in first command `-v /var/run.docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. there is `run.docker` and should be `run/docker`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A bit late, but this might help other users who are struggling with the same problem:

The problem here is that the `docker` group on your docker host has a different group id from the id of the `docker` group inside your container. Since the daemon only cares about the id and not about the name of the group your solution will only work if these id's match by accident.

The way to solve this is by either using tcp instead of using a unix socket by using the [-H option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option) when starting Docker engine. You should be **very careful** with this, as this allows anyone who has access to this port to gain root access to your system.

A more secure way of fixing this is making sure that the `docker` group inside the container ends up having the same group id as the `docker` group outside of the container. You can do this using build arguments for your `docker build`:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkinsci
ARG DOCKER_GROUP_ID

USER root
RUN curl -o /root/docker.tgz https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.12.5.tgz && tar -C /root -xvf /root/docker.tgz && mv /root/docker/docker /usr/local/bin/docker && rm -rf /root/docker*
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.7.1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN groupadd -g $DOCKER_GROUP_ID docker && gpasswd -a jenkins docker
USER jenkins
```

And then building it using

```
docker build \ 
  --build-arg DOCKER_GROUP_ID=`getent group docker | \ 
  cut -d: -f3` -t my-jenkins-image .
```

After this you can run your image and have docker access as non-root

```
docker run \ 
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ 
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -ti my-jenkins-image
```

Because this solution depends on supplying the correct group id to the docker daemon when the image is being built, this image would need to be built on the machine(s) where it is being used. If you build the image, push it and someone else pulls it on their machine, chances are that the group id's won't match again.

Comment: Ensuring that the `docker` group ID was consistent on the host and inside the container was exactly what we needed to fix when facing the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I used your dockerfile but did a small edit:

```
FROM jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN groupadd docker && gpasswd -a jenkins docker
USER jenkins
```

After building the image I can start it using (I'm on centos7):

```
docker run -d \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
     -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker:ro \
     -v /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02 \
     -v /lib64/libudev.so.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 \
     -p 8080:8080 \
     --name jenkins \
     --privileged=true -t -i \
test/jenkins
```

You tried to install the package docker.io inside your image. But this package is also on your host (otherwise it's not possible to run docker containers on it). So It's recommended to mount this to your container instead of installing it in your docker file. 
I think the mounted /lib64/... is specific for Centos 7.

```
$ docker exec -it 9fc27d5fcec1 bash
jenkins@9fc27d5fcec1:/$ whoami 
jenkins
jenkins@9fc27d5fcec1:/$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
9fc27d5fcec1        test                "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkins
```

Comment: I have the same question as the OP, I found this post to be helpful (though it does not solve the permissions issue).
http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/
The author advises against mounting the docker binary from the host to the container: "This is not reliable anymore, because the Docker Engine is no longer distributed as (almost) static libraries.".

Comment: It's some time ago I took a look. What do you mean that this isn't reliable anymore? I just started a container and mounted the .sock and bin and I can use docker in it (1.12) or am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: Honestly I'm not knowledgeable enough to give you a proper answer, I just wanted to point out that the link I posted advises against it.

Comment: I'm able to use docker inside my containers with mounting the sock + bin (which is the 'good' solution in the URL). I don't have to use the --priviledged flag it seems.

Comment: Oh now I see it's not reliable anymore. Something I have to explore.