# How to add user of jenkins container(jenkins) in group(users) inside container itself?

Tags: docker

When I access my container:

```
jenkins@bc145b8cfc1d:/$ docker ps
```

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

```
jenkins@bc145b8cfc1d:/$ whoami
jenkins
```

```
jenkins@9cdb24cf71f2:/$ usermod -G users jenkins
ERROR : usermod: Permission denied.**
```

Comment: You're running these commands in a container? Is Docker in the container? Have you mounted the Docker socket?

Comment: Jenkins is running in a container and docker is in host machine.we are trying to run docker commands from jenkins container and we have already mounted the docker socket.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount docker socket as volume in docker container with correct group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185035/how-to-mount-docker-socket-as-volume-in-docker-container-with-correct-group)

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a bash command inside a container as a different user. In this case you can run from your host:

```
docker exec -it --user root <container id> usermod -G users jenkins
```

or you can enter the container interactively and execute any commands as root as follows:

```
docker exec -it --user root <container id> bash
```

and then:

```
root@9cdb24cf71f2:/$ usermod -G users jenkins
```

**Note:** The solution above assumes that the group `users` exists.