# Airflow DockerOperator: connect sock.connect(self.unix_socket) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, airflow, operator-keyword

I am trying to get `DockerOperator` work with Airflow on my Mac. I am running Airflow based on [Puckel](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) with small modifications.

Dockerfile build as puckel-airflow-with-docker-inside:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:latest

USER root
RUN groupadd --gid 999 docker \
&& usermod -aG docker airflow
USER airflow
```

docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml.:

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:
    redis:
        image: 'redis:5.0.5'

    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    webserver:
        image: puckel-airflow-with-docker-inside:latest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
        volumes:
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3

    flower:
        image: puckel-airflow-with-docker-inside:latest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - redis
        environment:
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
        ports:
            - "5555:5555"
        command: flower

    scheduler:
        image: puckel-airflow-with-docker-inside:latest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - webserver
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery

        command: scheduler

    worker:
        image: puckel-airflow-with-docker-inside:latest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - scheduler
        volumes:
          - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
          - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
        environment:
          - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://socat:2375
          - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
          - EXECUTOR=Celery
        command: worker
    socat:
        image: bpack/socat
        command: TCP4-LISTEN:2375,fork,reuseaddr UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        expose:
          - "2375"
```

Task/Operation Definition in the DAG:

```py
DockerOperator(
    task_id='docker_command',
    image='centos:latest',
    api_version='auto',
    auto_remove=True,
    command="/bin/sleep 30",
    docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
    network_mode="bridge",
    dag=dag
)
```

Full Error-Log for the Docker-Task after triggering the DAG:

```
*** Log file does not exist: /usr/local/airflow/logs/tutorial/docker_command/2020-04-13T11:20:41.323461+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://6f57f4c44662:8793/log/tutorial/docker_command/2020-04-13T11:20:41.323461+00:00/1.log

[2020-04-13 11:20:47,627] {{taskinstance.py:655}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: tutorial.docker_command 2020-04-13T11:20:41.323461+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,648] {{taskinstance.py:655}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: tutorial.docker_command 2020-04-13T11:20:41.323461+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,648] {{taskinstance.py:866}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,648] {{taskinstance.py:867}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,648] {{taskinstance.py:868}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,660] {{taskinstance.py:887}} INFO - Executing <Task(DockerOperator): docker_command> on 2020-04-13T11:20:41.323461+00:00
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,663] {{standard_task_runner.py:53}} INFO - Started process 53 to run task
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,729] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: tutorial.docker_command 2020-04-13T11:20:41.323461+00:00 [running]> 6f57f4c44662
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,758] {{taskinstance.py:1128}} ERROR - Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 42, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 42, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 202, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 225, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 966, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py", line 262, in execute
    tls=tls_config
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 185, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 210, in _retrieve_server_version
    'Error while fetching server API version: {0}'.format(e)
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
[2020-04-13 11:20:47,765] {{taskinstance.py:1151}} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
[2020-04-13 11:20:57,585] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-04-13 11:20:57,584] {{local_task_job.py:103}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I can't get it to work :/. Am I maybe adding  - `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` the wrong way?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm seeing the same thing from linux.

Answer (score 7):

For me the following approach worked to get it run on my local machine:
I took the official docker-compose.yaml from here:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/docs/apache-airflow/start/docker-compose.yaml

In x-airflow-common:/volumes, I added:

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

In x-airflow-common:/user, I changed the value to

```
user: root
```

Starting Airflow with

```
docker-compose up airflow-init
docker-compose up
```

and the DAG with an DockerOperator runs through

Comment: Thank you! This worked and seemed to be the solution with the least amount of changes required.

Answer (score 3):

Found a elegant solution in the following link:

https://onedevblog.com/how-to-fix-a-permission-denied-when-using-dockeroperator-in-airflow/

From the link:

> There is a more elegant approach which consists of “wrapping” the file around a service (accessible via TCP).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Linux, and thanks to [How to mount docker socket as volume in docker container with correct group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185035/how-to-mount-docker-socket-as-volume-in-docker-container-with-correct-group) I solved it. Maybe my solution will help you.

I have next permissions on docker.sock:

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker docker.sock
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:latest
USER root
ARG DOCKER_GROUP_ID
# Install Docker
RUN pip install 'Docker==4.2.0'
# Add permissions for running docker.sock
RUN groupadd -g $DOCKER_GROUP_ID docker && gpasswd -a airflow docker
USER airflow
```

Build Image with command:

```
docker build --rm --build-arg DOCKER_GROUP_ID=`getent group docker | cut -d: -f3` -t docker-airflow .
```

And run Container with:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock://var/run/docker.sock -v /path/to/dags/on/your/local/machine/:/usr/local/airflow/dags docker-airflow webserver
```

Comment: is there an equivalnet way to do this using docker-compose.yaml from `curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.0/docker-compose.yaml'` directly from their website: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html. I am using their yaml file not puckels. I am getting this exact error when trying to run `dockerOperator`. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and i noticed my docker.socket lives in `/run/docker.socket`; when i enter, `systemctl status docker.socket`. What do you make of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. My setup for Airflow(airflow:2.2.2-python3.8) was with docker-compose, Ubuntu 20.04.

I was using [docker task decorator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html#using-the-taskflow-api-with-docker-or-virtual-environments). Below are the steps I did to resolve the error.

### Enabling TCP port 2375 for external connection to Docker

1. Create daemon.json file in /etc/docker:

```
 {"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]}
```

2. Add /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf

```
 [Service]
 ExecStart=
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

3. Reload the systemd daemon:

```sh
 systemctl daemon-reload
```

4. Restart docker:

```sh
 systemctl restart docker.service
```

5. Adding docker_url parameter in decorator

```py
@task.docker(
    image="custom-image",
    multiple_outputs=True,
    do_xcom_push=False,
    docker_url="tcp://host-ip:2375",
    mount_tmp_dir=False,
    mounts=[
    Mount(source="host/path/directory",target="container/path/directory",type="bind")
    ] 
)
def download_data():
    ...
```

**Note:**
The setup provides un-encrypted and un-authenticated direct access to the Docker daemon - and should be secured either using the built-in [HTTPS encrypted socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/), or by putting a secure web proxy in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my problem was a bit more generic "Run a docker command inside a docker container", but I was getting the same error as in the subject line. What worked for me was this answer: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337/2

Answer (score -2):

In my case the problem was that the docker service was not started.

I'm on **OpenSUSE** and `systemctl status docker.service` was showing it's inactive.

So - after I ran `sudo systemctl start docker.service` - and the status command showed it's active and running - then docker-compose ran successfully.