# Docker-compose exceptions

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Overflow!
I tried to transfer my docker-compose script from my ubuntu-workstation to my fedora laptop. when hitting

```
docker-compose up
```

I get following exception;

```
[polito@localhost dev]$ docker-compose up
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
File "http/client.py", line 1252, in request
File "http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
File "http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
File "http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
File "http/client.py", line 966, in send
File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
[...]
```

What I tried:
After googleing I found: deleting and reinstalling - did not work either.

Any idea how to fix?

Greetings!

Comment: how did you install docker-compose?

Comment: Maybe this will help [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61339850/8214791) and what says `docker-compose status`?

Comment: @Stefano yes, i installed it: docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192

Comment: @GregorWedlich 
[polito@localhost ~]$ docker-compose status
No such command: status

    Commands:
     build              Build or rebuild services


I am just spinning up a Keycloak in my docker-compose, no python needed there..

Comment: Then you should install docker-compose correctly. Something seems to be wrong.

Comment: @GregorWedlich: but there's no status command in docker-compose. why should it work? I think some python3 library is missing instead. That's why I was asking how the docker-compose was installed

Comment: @R.Polito: try to install docker-compose using `pip install docker-compose` (on some distros you might need `pip3`) as specified in https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-using-pip

Comment: Yes Ignore that please. I also meant docker-compose version. And that works for you.

Comment: @GregorWedlich reinstalled, still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, follow these steps: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/. It helped me.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue on my side. The docker daemon simply wasn't up.

```bash
sudo systemctl start docker
```

fixed it for me

Comment: Handled specifically for macOS at [apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373888](//apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373888).

Answer (score 0):

Please re-install docker-compose

Example:

```
$ sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

$ docker-compose --version
```

Comment: docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192, same exception

Comment: Have you tested the installation with pip? Maybe it is a Fedora specific problem.

Comment: I don't think we can help you. Would have to see what is in your compose file and how your environment is structured.

Comment: sure, sorry

version: "3"

services:
  # KEYCLOAK STUFF    
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: jboss/keycloak
    ports:
    - 8081:8080
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: mariadb
      DB_ADDR: authenticationDB
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL: JDBC_PING
      JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES: datasource_jndi_name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,info_writer_sleep_time=500
    depends_on:
      - authenticationDB

Comment: authenticationDB:
    container_name: authenticationDB
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./keycloakDB:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "--silent"]

Comment: @GregorWed'll just reroll to ubuntu - I know it's working there..

Comment: Yes i think is better. I also work with docker only on Debian or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Meight not be an answer but: I rerolled back to Ubuntu and updated the kernel to work with "Ryzen 5 4500U"

Working fine now, still not knowing why it's not working on fedora :s

Answer (score -1):

I had a silly issue. I restarted the machine and forgot to check if the docker desktop is running or not. Make sure your docker instance is running. Hope it helps someone like me.